# What do I need to start developing a Calculator/Converter App?

Tags: android, sdk, native, calculator

Is a web based approach easier or native ?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=make+calculator+app+android&oq=make+calculator+app+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6463j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Learn Java, then Android, then start coding

Comment: Thanks guys...Now please help me reverse my ban on Asking Questions which was apparently handed over thanks to all the negative votes...

Comment: @codeMagic I appreciate your help but unfortunately this has blocked me from asking questions any more. Please help me reverse that...please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing complex with the Calculator type of Apps. If you wanna do it in Android, do it native, you don't need to learn the whole SDK for that. The other option could be to do it as Web based. You can use phone gap for that. And there is another way to make it hybrid. You can use Cordova Plugins for this. What it does is, it keeps the logic in the JavaScript and creates user interface Natively.

But again this is pretty much general question. You need to come up with the idea first to get more useful answers.